# How to use Twig global parameter inside Twig function

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to use twig parameter I defined in config.yml:

```
twig:
    globals:
        my_path: "my_path"
```

in twig function asset() to concatenate "my_path" with the rest part of a path.

I tried:

```
src="{{ asset( my_path . 'the_rest_part_of_a_path') }}"
```

and even:

```
src="{{ asset( {{my_path}} . 'the_rest_part_of_a_path') }}"
```

Both are not working.

Is there any way I can use twig global parameter in that scenario?

Or maybe I can use symfony parameter defined in parameters.yml in such way?

Comment: `src="{{ asset(my_path ~ 'other_path') }}"` not tested

Comment: `~` is used for string concat, not `.`

Comment: @Xatenev Post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @JacekDziurdzikowski I've added my comment as an answer.

Comment: @martias Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twig uses ~ for string concatenation thus your example should be:

```
src="{{ asset(my_path ~ 'other_path') }}"
```

From the [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators)

> ~: Converts all operands into strings and concatenates them. {{ "Hello " ~ name ~ "!" }} would return (assuming name is 'John') Hello John!.